# Como mudar o nome de um projeto tipo web em uma solução no visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Galera, sempre que tento incluir um novo projeto web na minha solução com o nome "Web" ele adiciona "(algo número)" e eu não consigo mudar. Como eu faço para alterar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No arquivo C:\Users\Username\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config, você tem uma seção de sites

```
< sites >
...
< /sites >
```

Todos os sites (projetos) já abertos estão ai. Após apagar todos os itens, ao criar um novo website nenhum número será exibido.
Mas lembre de somente apagar os itens de sites/projetos e não o arquivo inteiro.